# How to use the predict function with categorical interaction terms in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `predict()` to find prediction values for a linear regression pertaining to kick offs in football. My model is:

```
fit8 <- lm(endyl ~ gdate + kt + rt+ ylr + gdate*rt + kt*ylr + gdate*kt
           + gdate*kt*ylr, data = returned_kicks)
```

`endyl` and `ylr` are numerical, but `gdate`, `kt`, and `rt`, are all categorical with 4, 32, and 32 levels respectively. As you can see there are 4 interaction terms and they use the categorical predictors. My attempt at predicting looks like this:

```
newdata1 <- with(returned_kicks, data.frame(gdate = factor('Nov', levels = c('Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')),
   kt = factor("ATL", levels =c("ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "CHI", "CIN", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET", "GB", "HOU", "IND", "JAX", 
                                                     "KC", "LA", "MIA","MIN", "NE", "NO", "NYG", "NYJ", "OAK", "PHI","PIT", "SD", "SEA", "SF", "TB", "TEN", "WAS")),
                                        rt = factor("BUF", levels =c("ARI", "ATL", "BAL", "BUF", "CAR", "CHI", "CIN", "CLE", "DAL", "DEN", "DET", "GB", "HOU", "IND", "JAX", 
                                                                     "KC", "LA", "MIA","MIN", "NE", "NO", "NYG", "NYJ", "OAK", "PHI","PIT", "SD", "SEA", "SF", "TB", "TEN", "WAS")), ylr = -5))
newdata1
predict.lm(fit8, newdata = newdata1, type = "response")
```

I have seen some places say including the levels like that helps with categorical predictors, but it doesn't seem to be accounting for the interaction terms. Am I doing something wrong in the predict function or am I setting up the `data.frame` wrong? Any suggestions on how to fix the error are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You just need to give `predict` a data frame with the levels of each factor variable for which you want predictions. In this case, `newdata1=data.frame(gdate="Nov", kt="ATL", rt="BUF", ylr=-5)` is all you need. If you want predictions for more combinations, just include them in `newdata1`. For example, `newdata1=expand.grid(gdate=c("Nov","Dec"), kt=c("ATL","BAL"), rt="BUF", ylr=c(-5,0,5))`

Comment: I tried that first and kept getting the error: Warning message:
In predict.lm(fit8, newdata = newdata1, type = "response") :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading       and the predicion was way off

Comment: rank-deficiency usually means that one of your variables is constant, or that some variables are not fully independent (with interaction terms, it may mean that some of the interaction levels do not occur in your training data), or that you simply have not enough data to reliably fit your model. So this is probably not related to your categorical predictors.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you saying that, for example, it may be that Atl did not ever have a kick that landed on the 5 yard line and so there is nothing in the data for the level of kt*ylr 'ATL'*5 ? Therefore it cant make a prediction of this. Will the regression still make accurate predictions where that interaction term does exist in the data or do I need to remove the interaction term from my data since some levels do not exist?

Comment: On rank deficiency, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it).